# Execute Scala code using oozie spark action gives exit code [-1] error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, oozie

I am trying to execute a scala code using Oozie spark action. But ending up with the error shown below:

```
oozi-W@spark-node] Launcher ERROR, reason: Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain], exit code [-1]
```

My workflow.xml is given below.

```
<action name='spark-node'>
        <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>

        <job-xml>${nameNode}/user/${wf:user()}/${examplesRoot}/apps/spark/hive-conf.xml</job-xml>

            <master>${master}</master>
            <name>ToyPredictor</name>
            <class>org.scala.model.ToyPredictor</class>
         <jar>${nameNode}/user/${wf:user()}/${examplesRoot}/apps/spark/lib/ToyPredictor-1.4.jar,${nameNode}/user/${wf:user()}/${examplesRoot}/apps/spark/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar,${nameNode}/user/${wf:user()}/${examplesRoot}/apps/spark/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar,${nameNode}/user/${wf:user()}/${examplesRoot}/apps/spark/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar
            </jar>

        <arg>34</arg>
            <arg>0</arg>
        <arg>34</arg>
            <arg>${nameNode}/tmp/ScalaOut-data/</arg>

        </spark>
        <ok to="end" />
        <error to="fail" />
    </action>
```

Iam able to execute example spark action provided in the Oozie documentation. But when trying to execute this scala code using spark action I get the error above. 
Any advice or pointers to sample scala code executiosn using oozie is much appreciated.

Comment: if you use yarn mode, check AM's logs (usually at http://<resource manager host>:8088)

Comment: `[AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.util.MRApps: cache file (mapreduce.job.cache.files) hdfs://severusdev-master1.epic.com:8020/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20160503130727/spark/aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar conflicts with cache file (mapreduce.job.cache.files) hdfs://severusdev-master1.epic.com:8020/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20160503130727/oozie/aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar This will be an error in Hadoop 2.0 `


I see this in the AM logs. Is this an issue ?

Comment: It seems so. Try to redeploy oozie's sharelib to keep it consistent.